# Is there a difference between renaming branch and reset --hard branch?

Tags: git

For example, if I have branchA pointing to commitA, and branchB pointing to commitB, now I would like to swap it, i.e. make branchA pointing to commitB, and branchB pointing to commitA.

There are two ways to do it.

First approach, by renaming:

```
git checkout branchA
git branch -m branchDummy
git checkout branchB
git branch -m branchA
git checkout branchDummy
git branch -m branchB
```

Alternatively, I can do:

```
git checkout branchA
git branch branchDummy
git reset --hard commitB
git checkout branchB
git reset --hard commitA
git branch --delete branchDummy
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: The `git branch -m` route will preserve reflogs.

Comment: @RomainValeri But I won't go this way **if the branches have been pushed and have remote tracking branches** because in the end it will track the wrong remote. Otherwise, it's OK.

Comment: @Philippe I'm not advocating for going *any* way, I'm stating a difference which could have been missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in terms of branch state. A branch is just a reference to a commit (see `.git/refs`). It doesn't matter how you assign value `[commit hash]` to the reference `branchA`. As long as the value is assigned.

But if you already have a remote branch and you have them associated using `--set-upstream` so that `git push` without parameters knows which branch to push to, then the renamed branch will keep referencing the old one.

Another, probably unimportant difference, is in the logs. Git captures the sequence of events in its logs inside `.git/logs` (accessible using `git reflog`). So since Git tracks what commits the branches pointed to and which commits you checked out, that part will be different. But only in your local repository - this information isn't pushed to remotes.

Comment: What about reflogs?

Comment: Sure, reflogs will be different :) It's a log after all and it does capture the sequence of steps. But it also will be different depending on which steps you do to rename the branch (do you do a checkout or not?). It doesn't seems like OP is worried about that.

Comment: I don't know about OP, but the question will be read by other people who could have that in mind too. I thought It'd be an improvement to mention it.

Comment: What about existing remote tracking branch configuration? In this case, I won't go with branch renaming but more on reset branches...

Comment: @Philippe, are you talking about the "connection" between local and remote-tracking branches when you push/pull without explicitly specifying which remote branches you're dealing with?

Comment: Yes, if he takes the branches renaming path, he will end up with tracking remotes inverted (local `branchA` pushed to `origin/branchB` for example)

Comment: @Philippe good point! Added this to the answer, thanks! PS: personally I haven't created local branches in years.. Just a FYI, maybe people who stumble upon this would like the fully-detached approach: https://github.com/ctapobep/blog/issues/10

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IDs of `commitA` and `commitB` there is no need for a third branch. And, for this specific purpose, there's no difference.... you could also have fun by just moving the pointers around instead of dancing your working tree around:

```
git checkout --detach
git branch -f branchA commitB
git branch -f branchB commitA
```